# React Router DOM v6 - Components Fail to Remount with Each Route Change

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

```
import React from "react";
import { BrowserRouter, Routes, Route, Navigate, Link } from "react-router-dom";

import "./styles.css";

function HomePage() {
  return <div className="page"> Page</div>;
}

function Test() {
  return <div className="page">Test Page</div>;
}

function ApplePage() {
  return <div className="page"> Page</div>;
}

export default function App() {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <div>
        <Link to="/" className="link">
          Home
        </Link>
        <Link to="/apple" className="link">
          Apple
        </Link>
        <Link to="/test" className="link">
          Test
        </Link>
      </div>
      <Routes>
        <Route
          path="/"
          element={
            <Wrapper>
              <HomePage />
            </Wrapper>
          }
        />

        <Route
          path="/apple"
          element={
            <Wrapper>
              <ApplePage />
            </Wrapper>
          }
        />

        <Route
          path="/test"
          element={
            <Wrapper>
              <Test />
            </Wrapper>
          }
        />
      </Routes>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}

const Wrapper = ({ children }) => {
  React.useEffect(() => {
    console.log("wrapper mounted>>>>");
  }, []);

  return children;
};
```

-------

Tech - react-router-dom v6 and react 18.2.0
Based on the provided code snippet, I expected the wrapper component to remount whenever the route changes. However, the observed behavior is that the wrapper remains mounted persistently, irrespective of route changes.

why each route isn't receiving a fresh instance of the wrapper component. This can be confirmed by checking the console log which is logged when wrappers mounts

[sandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/react-router-v6-forked-jzvgkt?file=%2Fsrc%2Fstyles.css%3A1%2C1-14%2C1&layout=%257B%2522sidebarPanel%2522%253A%2522EXPLORER%2522%252C%2522rootPanelGroup%2522%253A%257B%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522UNKNOWN%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522ROOT_LAYOUT%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522UNKNOWN%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522vertical%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522cltslfq9000063b6mou4z9t85%2522%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%252C0%255D%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522cltslfq9000023b6mfeutl40c%2522%257D%255D%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522cltslfq9000033b6mcg2a31j9%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%255D%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522vertical%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522cltslfq9000053b6mhewm6gjy%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B50%252C50%255D%257D%252C%2522tabbedPanels%2522%253A%257B%2522cltslfq9000023b6mfeutl40c%2522%253A%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522cltslfq9000023b6mfeutl40c%2522%252C%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522cltwilcxa00023b6lqpaibo2p%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522FILE%2522%252C%2522initialSelections%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522startLineNumber%2522%253A1%252C%2522startColumn%2522%253A1%252C%2522endLineNumber%2522%253A14%252C%2522endColumn%2522%253A1%257D%255D%252C%2522filepath%2522%253A%2522%252Fsrc%252Fstyles.css%2522%252C%2522state%2522%253A%2522IDLE%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522cltwilcxa00023b6lqpaibo2p%2522%257D%252C%2522cltslfq9000053b6mhewm6gjy%2522%253A%257B%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522cltslfq9000043b6mavp7cjd3%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522UNASSIGNED_PORT%2522%252C%2522port%2522%253A0%252C%2522path%2522%253A%2522%252F%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522cltslfq9000053b6mhewm6gjy%2522%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522cltslfq9000043b6mavp7cjd3%2522%257D%252C%2522cltslfq9000033b6mcg2a31j9%2522%253A%257B%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%255D%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522cltslfq9000033b6mcg2a31j9%2522%257D%257D%252C%2522showDevtools%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522showShells%2522%253Afalse%252C%2522showSidebar%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522sidebarPanelSize%2522%253A15%257D)

Comment: This is the way React works, it is an optimization that saves from tearing down and remounting the same component with the same "state and props", e.g. when nothing really changed. Is this all you needed to know or do you have some actual issue or problem because of this ooptimization?

Answer (score 0):

This has something to do with how React renders components on the screen. When react-dom triggers a render, react checks to see what components have changed. Since it's seeing the same Wrapper component, it doesn't unmount and remount a new one (you can test this out by passing a prop to 1 one on the wrapper components and you'll see that it does mount and unmount).

I'm not quite sure why you'd want to run code on every url change, but if you did you could

```
...

function TestPage = ()=><Wrapper><Test/></Wrapper>:


export default function App() {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
    ...
      <Routes>
       ...
        <Route
          path="/test"
          element={
           <TestPage/>
          }
        />
      </Routes>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}

const Wrapper = ({ children }) => {
  React.useEffect(() => {
    console.log("wrapper mounted>>>>");
  }, []);

  return children;
};
```

Although if you just wanted to wrap the children in a sort of layout, I would do something like this:

```
const Wrapper = ({ children }) => {
  React.useEffect(() => {
    console.log("wrapper mounted>>>>");
  }, []);

  return <Outlet/>
};
  <Routes>
     <Route
          element={
           <Wrapper/>
          }
        >
    enter other routes here
     </Route>
  </Routes>
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the efforts to answer! 

I know the first soln works I had already tried that. I was just trying to understand wts happening bts.

So lets say if we have an APP component which renders nothing but a <Dummy /> comp twice. I noticed that in this case it maintains  two separate instance 

I was expecting same behaviour in this case as each route renders it own element

Comment: For react, the tree that is rendered is the same though. React doesn't care about the route component and just sees the same Wrapper components in the same place and thus doesn't render a new one